# Maya: How can i bind multiple meshes to a skeleton?

Tags: 3d, maya, unreal-engine4, autodesk

i just created and rigged my character, but my character has a hat and some other aparrels, so my question is is there some easy way to bind the hat to the head bone?
i tried to parent it to the bone, but then i can't import it to unreal engine properly.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import them separately, and then create a Blueprint for the character, which contains 2 meshes component (maybe Skeletal for the body and Static for the hat?) and assemble them together.

Comment: I ended up doing that, also i could parent the objects to bones and the import error was because of my export setting in maya were wrong